# linkedin api v2 endpoint

Tags: linkedin-api

Recently, I was told that we should have migrated to v2 for my application. As a result of this info, I'm trying to migrate an application to v2.

However, I have searched on stackoverflow and a lot suggest that you need to subscribe as partner to get access to v2 api

request always return:
"message": "Not enough permissions to access

here: https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program

Linkedin in the migration guide says:
What about existing developer applications? If your developer application has made a successful v1 API request since October 1, 2018, your developer application automatically has access to the v2 API.

so I don't think I need to compile the form the become a partner.

What is my problem?

Comment: Which URL did you use when you get "Not enough permission..."? You should have access to `GET /v2/me`

Comment: I am getting successful response from "v2/me" endpoint but  v2/people/id:{peopleid}  endpoint return "not enough permission to access:Get/people/id:{peopleid}"